# How to get monitor resolution from Python API?

Tags: python, scripting

Is there a way to get the monitor resolution using the Python API?

Comment: More a python question than a blender question, and already has an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to StackOverflow site